# Larger brackets while using \tag in align environment

Tags: align, tag

I have the following equation, where its tag is very long:

```
\begin{align}
\tag{\parbox{4cm}{\center{Very very very very very very long tag}}}
\mathrm{\sum\limits_{i=1}^K} (ay_i + by_i + cy_i + dy_i + ey_i)
\end{align}
```

This code produces the following:

[image]

I am using \parbox to fit it into a smaller size. Doing so, the brackets of the tag remain small. I was wondering if it is possible to adjust their size to meet the height of the tag.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In my opinion you're abusing `\tag`, which is meant to set a label, not explanatory text.

Comment: Thank you! :) I suppose I am having this problem primarily because my equation is too long, and the original tag I am using is actually relatively short. I had to use \parbox to fit it in the same line as equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\tag*` and add the parentheses yourself.

But in my opinion this is abusing `\tag`, so I add an alternative version. With `varwidth` the box is set to the widest length that doesn't overshoots the specified width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^K (ay_i + by_i + cy_i + dy_i + ey_i)
\tag*{$\left(\begin{varwidth}{4cm}\centering Very very very very very very long tag\end{varwidth}\right)$}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^K (ay_i + by_i + cy_i + dy_i + ey_i)
\qquad
\left(\begin{varwidth}{4cm}\centering Very very very very very very long description\end{varwidth}\right)
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `\mathrm` is just wrong where you put it.

Comment: A question about the second, alternative version with_out `\tag`. Is it possible to flush the explanatory text to the right edge? Similarly to how using `\tag` does it. Something automatic, hopefully?

Comment: @LinearChristmas The idea is that flushing to the right isn’t the best choice

Comment: Yes, maybe so. I see that flushing to the right is a bad choice in some cases. For example, when one will use a tag in addition to explanatory text, which should be further to the right than the explanatory text. However, if one has tags in some places and (instead of tags) explanatory text elsewhere but nearby, two _different_ kinds of alignment look peculiar. Perhaps I am alone in this? :)

Comment: @LinearChristmas You may use `flalign`. But don't, unless you want to be alone… `;-)`

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try. Some alone-time is occasionally a good idea. :)